# Valorant shows no internet connection

Tags: windows-10, valorant

I tried to install Valorant but installer shows not able to connect to internet, I have checked the connection and it works fine with others. When I use VPN service it works fine.

So I installed it using VPN (The location of VPN is same as my country)

But how do I use it without VPN.